# Css boxshadow to uplift an image

Tags: html, css

I have a background wrapper. I want to make it with css instead of adding an image. I am not sure how to add box shadow so as i can get the same output as in attached image.

[image]

I know that box shadow property will be used here.

but just not sure how to use this to get the same output.
i tried using

```
box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

Comment: I'm not sure CSS3 will give you the granular level of control you require to only shadow teh 'folded' part of that image. If you want to shadow one or more complete sites it works really well, but not sure it'll do what you want here...

Comment: @LDJ yes it will. By combining it with some selectors and some transforms it can be achieved. It is not so straightforward though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="box effect3">
    <h3>Effect 3</h3>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box h3{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}

.effect3
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect3:before
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

Source is this [post](http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects) from paulund

Also if you want check this JQuery plugin out:

[Shadows with JQuery](http://syddev.com/jquery.shadow/)

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the `Box-shadow:` rule in your CSS.

## css example

```
#example1 {
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; //mozilla support
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; //webkit support
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

However box-shadow like most css3 rules will not work in earlier versions of ie.

The box-shadow property can accept a comma-separated list of shadows, each defined by 2-4 length values (specifying in order the horizontal offset, vertical offset, optional blur distance and optional spread distance of the shadow), an optional color value and an optional ‘inset‘ keyword (to create an inner shadow, rather than the default outer shadow).

## The Syntax:

```
box-shadow: none | <shadow> [ , <shadow> ]*
<shadow> = inset? && [ <length>{2,4} && <color>? ]
```

[image]

## [More Information Here to Get You Started](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)